# Should I use universal quantification in lemma formulation?

Tags: isabelle

For

```
datatype natural = Zero | Succ natural

primrec add :: "natural ⇒ natural ⇒ natural"
where
  "add Zero m = m"
| "add (Succ n) m = Succ (add n m)"
```

I prove

```
lemma add_succ_right: "⋀ m n. add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"
```

For being mathematical, it is important to have universal quantification. However, for using this fact in the simplifier, it is better to do it without:

```
lemma add_succ_right_rewrite: "add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"
```

What is the common wisdom about these versions, which one should I prefer in what circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isabelle/HOL has three ways to universally quantify over variables in lemma statements:

```
 lemma 1: "⋀m n. add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"

 lemma 2:
   fixes m n
   shows "add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"

 lemma 3: "∀m n. add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"
```

Additionally, free variables in lemma statements become automatically quantified:

```
 lemma 4: "add m (Succ n) = Succ (add m n)"
```

Lemmas 1, 2, and 4 yield the same theorem, which can be used in identical ways later on. Lemma 3 uses the HOL universal quantifier instead of the quantification from the meta-logic. Therefore, extra work is needed to instantiate the quantifier in lemma 3. Thus, this version should only be used in special circumstances.

The version in lemma 1 dates back to when the Isar language was not in its current state and is thus somewhat out-dated. Therefore, I would suggest to prefer version 2 (if you want to explicitly mention the quantified variables), or 4 (if not).

Comment: "Free variables in lemma statements become automatically quantified" -- by using schematic variables in the proved statement?

Comment: Yes, free variables and turned automatically into schematic variables when they leave the scope where they are fixed (either explicitly with `fixes` or implicitly as part of the command `lemma`).